# Is this approach correct to calculate/prove this problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

In $\triangle{ABC}, \angle{CAB}=10^{\circ}, \angle{ACB}=20^{\circ}$. Now make line CD so that $\angle{BCD}=60^{\circ}$ and AC=CD. Solve $\angle{CBD}$.

Here is my solution:
Start from equilateral triangle $\triangle{AEC}$:

[image]

Then we make line CB and EB so that $\angle{ACB}=20^{\circ}$ and $\angle{CEB}=20^{\circ}$.

[image]

$\angle{ECA}=60^{\circ}$

$\implies \angle{EBC}=180^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-20^{\circ}-20^{\circ}=80^{\circ}$

$\implies \angle{ECB}=\angle{EBC}$

$\implies EB=EC=EA$

$\angle{AEB}=40^{\circ}, EA=EB$

$\implies \angle{EAB}=\angle{EBA}=70^{\circ}$

$\implies \angle{CAB}=10^{\circ}$.

Then we extend EB to D so that $CD=EC$.

[image]

$CD=EC \implies \angle{BDC}=\angle{BEC}=20^{\circ}$

$\implies \angle{BCD}=180^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-20^{\circ}-20^{\circ}-20^{\circ}=60^{\circ}$

$\implies \angle{CBD}=180^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-20^{\circ}=\boxed{100^{\circ}}$.

I wonder if this approach is strictly and logically correct to solve $\angle{CBD}$ or to prove it's $100^{\circ}$? Thanks.

Comment: Related (same problem, different solutions): ["Geometry Problem on $\triangle ABC$ and Angle Chasing"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3642725/409). There may be others.

Comment: Great link and resource. Thanks! My main curiosity is not the answer but wonder if this approach is solid and correct.

Comment: You should correct this $$\angle{BCD}=180^{\circ}-60^{\circ}-20^{\circ}-20^{\circ}=60^{\circ}$$ You forgot to subtract another angle of $20^{\circ}$.

Comment: I see timon92 approach in the link starts very similar to this approach but this approach does not prove collinearity of three points.

Comment: @Angelo yes that's a typo fixed. Thanks for good catching!

Comment: I think your approach is correct.

Comment: @Angelo Thanks!